$2\pi$-rotation of fermionic states vs. fermionic operators
Given a fermionic state $|\Psi\rangle$, a $2\pi$ rotation should transform it as
\begin{equation}
|\Psi\rangle \quad\to\quad -|\Psi\rangle \,,
\end{equation}
On the other hand, given a fermionic operator $\psi$, under a $2\pi$ rotation it should transform as
\begin{equation}
\psi \quad \to \quad -\psi
\end{equation}
(see for example Tong's QFT lectures, eq. (4.28)).
I cannot see how this is consistent however. Given some matrix element $\langle\Psi'|\psi|\Psi\rangle$, under a $2\pi$ rotation it should naively transform either as

$\langle\Psi'|\psi|\Psi\rangle \; \to \; (-1)^2\langle\Psi'|\psi|\Psi\rangle$, or
$\langle\Psi'|\psi|\Psi\rangle \; \to \; (-1)\langle\Psi'|\psi|\Psi\rangle$.

Depending on which of the rules I previously mentioned (transform states or operators) is applied.
Question 1: How is the apparent inconsistency fixed?
Question 2: Transforming the operator, it is suggested that there should be some observable in nature which changes its sign as the detector is rotated by $2\pi$, since $\langle\mathcal{O}\rangle \;\to\; -\langle\mathcal{O}\rangle$. This is never observed though. Is the conclusion wrong?

The point is that if $|{\Psi}\rangle$ and $|{\Psi'}\rangle$ have definite fermion parity (which is implicit in your argument to conclude that they are invariant under $2\pi$ rotation), then these matrix elements are 0 and there is no problem. Or, they do not have well defined fermion parity (unphysical, but mathematically fine), then they are not invariant under $2\pi$ rotation.

There are no arrows in physics, there are no arrows in math. $|\Psi\rangle\to-|\Psi\rangle$ is just bad notation. You should always write equalities only. The correct statement is $U(2\pi)|\Psi\rangle=-|\Psi\rangle$ and $U(2\pi)\psi U(2\pi)^\dagger=-\psi$. Both these statements are correct, and compatible with each other. Also $\langle \Psi'|\psi|\Psi\rangle$ vanishes by Wigner-Eckart so there is no issue to begin with...

The point is that  fermionic operators are not  observables for many reasons. For instance they do not commute for causally separated arguments.  You need two (an even number of) fermionic operators to construct an observable. E.g. currents $\overline{\Psi}\gamma_\mu \Psi$.  Here signs do not crate problems...

I totally agree it is physically sensible they are not observables. Must it be assumed a priori though? Or is there anything preventing us from even trying to force it (say e.g. you picked a majorana)?

The most difficult point are anticommutation relations for spacelike separated arguments. These are valid also for Maiorana  quaum  fields. It is quite difficult to dirctly interpret these  correlations in the spirit of standard QFT and its formulation of causality...

@Mateo This is the parity superselection.
